# how to find center of mass in each segments based on foreground pixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition

am working on word image i want to find the center of mass in each segments.

```
clear all;
close all;
a = imread('i2e.jpg');
figure;imshow(a);

% Normalizatoin

b = imresize(a,[50,50]);
figure;imshow(b);
% Binarization
th = graythresh(b);
a = im2bw(b,th);
figure,imshow(a);
w = 5;
h = 5;
c = 50/h;
r = 50/w;
cellA = cell(w,h);

% apply grid basid on rows and column
a(r:c:end,:,:) = 0;
a(:,r:c:end,:) = 0;
figure,imshow(a);
count = 0;
for p1 =1:50
    for q1 =1:50
       r1 = p1 + r;
       c1 = q1 + c;

        if(p1 < 50 || q1 < 50)
           count = 0;
            for  i = 1 : r
              for  j = 1 : c
                  r1 = i + r;
                  c1 = j + c;
                  if(a(i,j) == 0)
                      count = count + 1;
                  end
              end
            end
        end
    end
end
count;
```

am not getting proper results please help me to find the center of mass in each segments

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqhA.jpg)

Comment: "am not getting proper results"... what does that mean? are you getting an error? are you getting results that are off by 1e-16? are you getting red-eyed bangswarkles coming out of your computer? what results do you expect?

Comment: Can you provide a sample image? If possible, also the result you get and those you want to get.

Comment: thank you all i got solution for my problem.